# Unable to apply Cloudflare SSL to Google Cloud/Worpress/Bitnami deployment

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have set up a website on Google Cloud Platform using WordPress/Bitnami and basically watched YouTube videos to do it, so a lot of the terminology is something I'm not familiar with!

So, as mentioned, I have created a website on Google Cloud Platform, using the Bitnami version of WordPress. I have obtained SSL certification from Cloudflare as this was recommended to me, however, when I try to apply this to my website, I have to update the nameservers to what has been instructed to me by Cloudflare, and as soon as I do this, my website no longer loads. Also, in order to get my website to load, I have to go back to the original Google nameservers, and when I do that, my website loads, HOWEVER, it then affects the Google email, in that it will allow emails to be sent, but I cannot receive emails! These issues are slowly pushing me towards insanity!

The original Google nameservers are as follows:

- ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com
- ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com
- ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com
- ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com

The nameservers that were advised to me by Cloudflare for the SSL are as follows:

- lauryn.ns.cloudflare.com
- miles.ns.cloudflare.com

This is the first website I've ever created, and I did it by watching YouTube tutorials. Very much hope someone can help, and if there's any further information you need in order to provide any help, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Get your web site working first, before trying to set up CloudFlare.

Comment: Well Michael, thank you for that valuable contribution. If you read my post, you would have noticed on two occasions, I mentioned that this was the first website i'd ever created, and it was done using YouTube tutorials. I perfectly understand that I need to get the website working first, which I thought I had done! Unfortunately, your comment does nothing to help me in any way whatsoever! If anyone else can offer anything slightly more valuable than Michael, I will be very grateful to hear it!

Comment: That IS exactly what you need to do. Stop trying to set up CloudFlare until your web site and email work without it. Then you can plan how to migrate to CloudFlare. Solve one issue at a time and don't introduce needless complexity while things are still not working.

Comment: I thought I had done that initially. The website and our emails was working absolutely fine. It was only after trying to apply the Cloudflare SSL DNS settings, that we started to experience these problems. Are you able to be more specific, and advise what specifically to do/where to look to pinpoint the problem please? Again, please be patient with me. I've never done anything like this before so naturally, i'm significantly less experienced than you are. Thank you

Comment: Hello, please provide in the question the complete configuration information, the steps you took to deploy your website, the youtube video you referenced and also the error message. Please also let us know whether you are using Cloud DNS - https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview

Comment: What does not work? What did you configure? My marbel is not working very well today... :)

Comment: Hi MonicaPC/Berndinox. Thank you for your offers to help. Thankfully, I approached Google Cloud Platform support and they were able to resolve these issues for me, and also set up SSL using load balancing, so apart form some mixed content errors, my woes are all over! Thank you again, and it's very nice to know that there are people who have the patience to help complete novices like me, instead of just stating the blatantly obvious! We all have to start somewhere. It's a shame Michael Hampton doesn't realise that. Very grateful to you both and thanks again!

Comment: Happy to hear the issue is resolved!